# Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

I have a strange problem on Centos 6.6 with rpm.

I try to install rpm/srpm and i get this message :

```
rpm -v --checksig glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.src.rpm 
glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.src.rpm:
Entête V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
Header SHA1 digest: BAD
V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
MD5 digest: BAD
```

And from another server with same os version :

```
rpm -v --checksig glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.src.rpm 
glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.src.rpm:
Entête V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: OK
Header SHA1 digest: OK (e9db7a50918ba3d42cbd7da1e8dc4fa6dac7949f)
V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: OK
MD5 digest: OK (bf01b4a34aafa0fbc2d28d741f6546aa)
```

Any idea ? There is somebody i can backup/.restore to the server who have trouble ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe the RPM was altered on copy. Do a checksum compare between the RPMs on the two servers.

Comment: 247359982ba6c898197d89e201ec3ccc vs 247359982ba6c898197d89e201ec3ccc checksum are the same

Comment: No idea. Maybe this thread helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376547/rpm-installation-error-header-v4-rsa-sha1-signature-bad-key-id

Comment: Ok found how to solve that : http://kiteplans.info/2015/01/15/solved-bug-centos-yum-rpm-broken-by-nss-softokn-3-14-3-19-el6_6-update-error-rpmts_hdrfromfdno-error-rpmdbnextiterator-header-v3-rsasha1-signature-key-id-bad/

Comment: Please post an answer if you've found a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

from : http://kiteplans.info/2015/01/15/solved-bug-centos-yum-rpm-broken-by-nss-softokn-3-14-3-19-el6_6-update-error-rpmts_hdrfromfdno-error-rpmdbnextiterator-header-v3-rsasha1-signature-key-id-bad/

Thus if you yum update only installed one of the packages you will end up with a broken YUM and RPM.
You might see error messages like these when trying to run YUM and RPM commands:
error: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID xxx BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h# 1784 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID xxx BAD
Most of the time you will have had nss-softokn-3.14.3-19 installed but not nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19

To fix this you have to:

**1. Manually download nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19**
yumdownloader nss-softokn-freebl or wget the RPMs

64-Bit servers / x86_64 run

```
wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19.el6_6.x86_64.rpm
```

32-Bit Servers / i686 run

```
wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/6.6/updates/i386/Packages/nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19.el6_6.i686.rpm
```

**2. Extract the RPM**

64-Bit servers / x86_64 run

```
rpm2cpio nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19.el6_6.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

32-Bit Servers / i686 run

```
rpm2cpio nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-19.el6_6.i686.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

**3. Copy .libfreeblpriv3.* to correct location**

64-Bit servers / x86_64 run

```
cp ./lib64/libfreeblpriv3.* /lib64
```

32-Bit Servers / i686 run

```
cp ./lib/libfreeblpriv3.* /lib
```

**4. Rerun Yum Update to update nss-softokn-freebl and FIX YUM and RPM**

yum update
If you still have problems you might have to reinstall yum as below for a 64bit server, 32bit servers will just need to locate the 32bit versions of the rpms! But most servers won’t need this:

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.2.29-60.el6.centos.noarch.rpm

wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch.rpm

wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64.rpm

rpm -ivh --nodeps yum-3.2.29-60.el6.centos.noarch.rpm

rpm -ivh yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch.rpm

rpm -ivh centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64.rpm
```

I have also had some questions about how to restore the rpmdb that got corrupted while trying to fix the problem, there are two ways:

First, copy a good copy of the /var/lib/rpm folder over from an identical good server of from a backups – you do have backups right?

On good server or from backup:

```
tar -cf rpmbackup.tar /var/lib/rpm
```

Then send the tar over to the bad server

On broken server:

```
cd /var/lib
mv /var/lib/rpm /var/lib/rpm.bak
tar -xf /location/to/rpmbackup.tar
```

Then you should be good to go!

The second way is to reinstall every rpm ever installed via checking the rpm install log. See the comment below

Bug Report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1182337